# Any tips for debugging model persistence with RavenDB

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, viewmodel, ravendb

Folks,
A system I am currently working on is comprised of many JavaScript tools which persist JSON data as strings in SQL Server.
I am looking at implementing a solution where Knockout ViewModels are passed back to MVC controllers as c# ViewModels and then persisted to RavenDB. Some of these Viewmodels are quite complex and I am getting exceptions when trying to save to the DocumentStore.

Is there any advice available on best practice for view model design, what is and is not allowed in models being persisted to RavenDB?

Also what is the best way to go about debugging a failed model persist? For example I am getting such errors as "Unable to case object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider'  Source=Raven.Abstractions. I need more info.

I suppose I am wondering why JSON that works with the Knockout ViewModel and which is bound correctly with the c# ViewModel is subsequently causing problems when persisting to Raven.

I have about 100 of these JSON ViewModels to implement so I need a good debug process and a guide to acceptable model structures for RavenDB persistence.

Comment: Can you post the code showing how you store the ViewModels in RavenDB?

Comment: @MattWarren MattI subsequently found that the definition of the ViewModel itself is not a problem. I can new up a fake instance it and store in raven. It has problems when storing a version posted back to the controller. When I look at the stack trace I can see there is a problem between the Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeConvertable call and the Raven.Abstractions.Json.JsonDynamicConverter.WriteJson call.It seems to be failing before even getting to Raven. I am going to examine

Comment: I am going to compare the fake and real instance to see what the offending property is, but this is an awkward and time consuming way to troubleshoot viewmodels. I'm hoping for a way to speed this process up.

Comment: Create some way for us to reproduce the problem, that would allows us to see what is going on and suggest a fix / debug methodology